# CodeIgniter replacing selected characters in all POST input

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, character-encoding, replace

I'm planning to convert an existing intranet system to CodeIgniter. I've always used UTF-8 throughout so it can handle all sorts of different characters, this is essential for the system (outputting invoices, address labels etc).

There's a few characters I decided to replace on input automatically as they often end up confusing the users of the system.

- Curly quotes, both single and double. Replaced with normal apostrophe/quotation marks
- En dash and em dash, replaced with a normal hyphen
- Ellipses, replaced with three full stops

At least these punctuation symbols are now all used and stored consistently.

Data that is to be stored in a database is always received by POST in this system, so I run the following function over the POST array on every page load...

```
function nasty_chars_replace(&$var) {

    $trans_table = array(
        chr(0xe2).chr(0x80).chr(0x9a) => '\'', //SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
        chr(0xe2).chr(0x80).chr(0x9e) => '"', //DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
        chr(0xe2).chr(0x80).chr(0xa6) => '...', //HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
        chr(0xe2).chr(0x80).chr(0x98) => '\'', //LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
        chr(0xe2).chr(0x80).chr(0x99) => '\'', //RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
        chr(0xe2).chr(0x80).chr(0x9c) => '"', //LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
        chr(0xe2).chr(0x80).chr(0x9d) => '"', //RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
        chr(0xe2).chr(0x80).chr(0x93) => '-', //EN DASH
        chr(0xe2).chr(0x80).chr(0x94) => '-' //EM DASH
    );

    foreach ($trans_table as $utf8_code => $replace) {
        $var = str_replace($utf8_code, $replace, $var);
    }

    return trim($var);
}
array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'nasty_chars_replace');
```

Is there a method for doing something similar in CodeIgniter, globally on all POST data (if POST is present)?

Does anyone else do anything like this?
Are there any other characters that are easily confused that I should consider "cleansing" (not sanitizing as such) for data consistency?
**EDIT:** Is this even a good idea?

**EDIT 2:** I should say that I also `trim()` all POST data as well to remove leading/trailing whitespace. So validation can fail if someone decides to just fill an input with whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to run this on all POST data without having the need to call the function *every time*, consider either placing it in the constructor of you controller, or, in the constructor of the parent of your controller.

### In Constructor of Controller:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if(!empty($_POST)) array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'nasty_chars_replace');
    }

    function index(){
        //typically a GET request, nasty_chars_replace will not execute.
    }

    function post_here1(){
        //will be nasty char cleaned.
    }

    function post_here2(){
        //will be nasty char cleaned.
    }

}
```

Now as you can imagine, this has to be written in the constructor of all your controllers. If you want to write it only once, consider extending your controllers from a base class first and write it in the constructor of the parent:

### In Constructor of Parent Controller:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if(!empty($_POST)) array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'nasty_chars_replace');
    }
}
```

...and back in **home.php**:

```
class Home extends MY_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index(){
        //typically a GET request, nasty_chars_replace will not execute.
    }

    function post_here1(){
        //will be nasty char cleaned.
    }

    function post_here2(){
        //will be nasty char cleaned.
    }
}
```

I encourage you to have a look at Phil Sturgeon's [Keeping It Dry](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY) post for more information on how to use this base class inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Well to answer part of your question - if you use CI's [input class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) it does the Security Filtering for you... The security filtering function is called automatically when a new controller is invoked.

So if you use **$this->input->post()** instead of $_POST.... It

> Filters the GET/POST/COOKIE array keys, permitting only alpha-numeric
>   (and a few other) characters.

The Input class has the ability to filter input automatically to prevent cross-site scripting attacks. If you want the filter to run automatically every time it encounters POST or COOKIE data you can enable it by opening your application/config/config.php file and setting this:

`$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;`

or only when required using TRUE as the second parameter.

```
$this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); // returns all POST items with XSS filter
```

so I suppose you can then extend the core Input class

```
class MY_Input extends CI_Input {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

and add your custom function in here to replace certain characters and trim the values.
Then this Input class pre-processes global input data for security and db consistency for you.

hope it helps

Comment: Yeah I saw that it processes the array keys, that's good. But XSS isn't what I'm asking here I'm afraid. I was wondering about replacing certain characters from a data storage/consistency perspective.

Comment: @benjobradley - yes you can extend Input Class and add your custom function in there. e.g. `class MY_Input extends CI_Input {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}`

Comment: that'll answer `Is there a method for doing something similar in CodeIgniter, globally on all POST data (if POST is present)?` i suppose?

Comment: Interesting. Where would I do that? In my controller? Is there somewhere it can go so it applies to all controllers?

Comment: Yes, you can apply to all controllers using Input class or Hooks. Have a look at these - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html and  http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want prevent XSS attack try using library from Codeigniter :

1. in application/config/autoload.php add this helper :

> $autoload['helper'] = array('security');

2. in application/config/config.php  set to this :

> $config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;

This will filter all GET, POST or COOKIE data from XSS attack and working fine